# How to embed web portal from SSRS 2016 into web page?

Tags: iframe, reporting-services, x-frame-options, ssrs-2016

We were using SSRS 2014 and had our web portal embedded in another enterprise internal web page using iFrame, everything is on the same network and it was working fine.

We upgraded SSRS to 2016 and now we get the message:

"This content cannot be displayed in a frame. To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame"

I tried to check if the web.config was different from 2014 but it's not so I don't know how to enable SSRS to be shown in frame.

I can embed individual reports but we used to have the portal so the users would be able to see all folders.

Anyone has experienced this?

Comment: Same problem over here. I think it has to do with "X-Frame-Options SameOrigin". As I understand is a build in feature in the SSRS web server. Have not figured out how to disable it. For report pages individually you can embed inside an iFrame using the rs:embed=true URL parameter but this does NOT work for the PORTAL

Comment: try adding "...&rs:Embed=true;" to the end of your url. this worked for most of my reports. I am still having issues with ssrs2016 reports rendering in sharepoint 2010 web part viewer.

Comment: We are trying to embed the portal itself and not a single report. Thanks for the trick in any case, it may be useful in the future for us.